# Cytoscape ignore "can not create edge with nonexistant target"

Tags: cytoscape.js

I would like to ignore the error that is returned by cytoscape when attempting to create an edge that points to an unexisting target.

For technical reasons, I can not make sure my edges are pointing to an existing targets.

If I directly pass

```
elements: myListOfEdgesAndNodes
```

When declaring the cy object, it fails and doesn't display anything because of that error.
I have thought of a workaround, which would be to initialize cy object with my nodes

```
elements: myListOfNodes
```

And then dynamically add edges in a loop with cy.add() in which case I believe the add will fail when the edge's target is non-existant, but it should not prevent other nodes/edges from being displayed. Does that sound like a good workaround ? Is there anything better to do ?

Comment: Can you provide an example and your current code (preferably as a snippet)?

Comment: Also, please show us the exact value of myListOfEdgesAndNodes, otherwise we'd have to guess whats wrong

Comment: Sorry perhaps I wasn't clear enough, there is nothing actually wrong here, this is the expected behavior when an edge points to a non-existing node. There are such edges in my graph. My question is how to bypass this behavior, and the solution that I considered in the OP works (loop through the edges and add them to the graph, while handling the exception raised for edges pointing to non-existing nodes), but it's very ressource consuming.

Comment: The error is thrown for a reason, I don't think your code should depend on non existing targets. Still, please share your code and the list of edges/nodes, otherwise I can't help (just guess)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the final `elements` array in your python scope, then you can easily filter out all those edges which point to a non-existing vertex.
Here is an example, which assumes the following typical scenario (as described [in the docs of the cytoscape-dash](https://dash.plotly.com/cytoscape/elements)):

1. all vertices have an explicit "id" field and no "source" field
2. all edges have "source" and "target" fields

```
def removeDanglingEdges(elements):
    vids = set([v['data']['id'] for v in elements if not 'source' in v['data']])
    return [e for e in elements if not 'source' in e['data'] or (e['data']['source'] in vids and e['data']['target'] in vids)]

# example usage
elements = [{'data':{'id':1}},{'data':{'source':1,'target':3}},{'data':{'id':3}},{'data':{'source':1,'target':6}}]
cleaned_elements = removeDanglingEdges(elements)
print(cleaned_elements) # -> [{'data':{'id':1}},{'data':{'source':1,'target':3}},{'data':{'id':3}}]
```